# "Unable to perform" issue in IIS Manager (localhost)

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-10

When I'm trying to open any app in IIS Manager (local machine) like CGI, Handler mappings etc. I got an error `There was an error while performing this operation`:

[image: Click here for image]

I'm unable to find out this issue.

Comment: Make sure `Web.config` exists in the home directory of the website and its NTFS permissions are allowing read

Comment: Can u please help how to check NTFS permissions..

Comment: You might try to use Jexus Manager to troubleshoot, as it might give a more meaningful error message, https://www.jexusmanager.com

Answer (score 0):

I installed the hosting bundle again. i.e. repair and then checked if the iis_usr has all access for the wwwroot folder.
This resolved the problem for me.